# Ubuntu saying No operating system found when installing

Tags: system-installation

I have a HP laptop with 500 GB hard disk. When I am trying to install ubuntu in my laptop it is showing that "there is no operating system found in your system do you want to install ?  the whole data will be lost." But I am already using WINDOWS 7. It is not showing the option along with WINDOWS 7. Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Boot into BIOS
2. Set the SATA mode to IDE
3. Set the SATA3 mode to AHCI
4. Install. You will need to change these settings back when you boot into Windows and vice versa, as Windows cannot boot with these settings.
5. It is likely the bootloader will not show up, but that can be fixed easily by first typing `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal
6. Then, run `sudo mount /dev/STEP_5_OUTPUT /mnt && sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`

Now you should be able to boot, but be sure to revert the changes to BIOS to boot Windows and vice versa

Answer (score -2):

Most of the time this happens when you didn't install the bootloader in the correct place during installation or somehow the MBC got corrupted. If you really want to access windows 7 again insert your windows 7 recovery disc. Other than that the only thing you need to do is reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Uhm, I think you misunderstood the question. The OP is in the Ubuntu installer - Ubuntu isn't installed yet at this point.