# Installing ubuntu: no operating system is currently installed on this computer

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

I want to install ubuntu on a new desktop. So I followed the [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation):

1. I downloaded an iso file (I've tried Ubuntu 14 and Ubuntu 16 already).
2. I mounted it on a USB stick (I tried many sticks and few programs, such as iso2usb on Windows and Startup Disc Creator on Ubuntu)
3. I set the booting sequence on my desktop computer (I'm sure it's booting from my USB stick now).

However, when I try boot the desktop computer, I still have the error:

> No operating system is currently installed on this computer.

And this is true, it's a new one.

I did some research and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314294/ubuntu-saying-no-operating-system-found-when-installing) question which seems to be exactly like mine. So I wanted to set the SATA mode to IDE, but there is no such option in my BIOS. I have following options: disabled (I tried setting that and it didn't help), ATA, AHCI, RAID On.

Also, I wanted to set the SATA3 mode to AHCI, but I have no such option.

The secure boot option is disabled.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change anything else in BIOS?

Comment: Are there any options in the bios to change the priority of boot devices ? If so, make sure it's set to boot from the USB stick. Another possiblility might be that you have to press a specific key during bootup - do you see something like "press F12 to select boot device" ?  If that doesn't work, try a different USB stick, and a different USB port. Perhaps burning the ISO to a DVD and installing from that is an option ? What make / model is your desktop or motherboard ?

Comment: @JonasCz, yes, they are. And I changed the booting sequence. I'm sure it's booting from my USB stick (or at lest, it tries to boot from it). Yes, I tried a different USB stick and a different USB port. I could install it from a DVD, but I'm hoping to be able to use my USB instead.

Comment: Set your boot sequence, to usb

Comment: @looserof7, please, read my question: **I set the booting sequence on my desktop computer.**

Comment: Yeah, usb should be first

Comment: @looserof7, I know, this is why I set the booting sequence in a way that usb is first. However, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try using Rufus, as described in the help page: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows - not sure what else could be the problem though.

Comment: @JonasCz, thanks, it works now! But I don't understand why. I mean is Iso2USB a useless program? I used it 2 years ago to install Ubuntu and it worked.

Comment: Maybe it's no longer maintained and doesn't work with newer ISOs ? Not sure though. You say you used Startup Disk creator on ubuntu, and that didn't work either, which is wiered, because it's part of ubuntu and officially maintained. No idea why that didn't work either though.